# Convexity $\phi(\boldsymbol t)=\boldsymbol{c}'I^{-1}(\boldsymbol t)\boldsymbol{c}$ w.r.t. $\boldsymbol t$

Tags: matrices, statistics, convex-analysis

I am trying to check convexity of $\phi(\boldsymbol t)=\boldsymbol{c}'I^{-1}(\boldsymbol t)\boldsymbol{c}$ w.r.t. $\boldsymbol t=(t_1,\ldots,t_m)'$, where $I^{-1}(\boldsymbol t)$ is the variance-covariance matrix given by

$$I^{-1}(t)=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   f(\boldsymbol t) & g(\boldsymbol t) \\
   g(\boldsymbol t) & h(\boldsymbol t) \\
  \end{array} } \right],
$$
where $f(\boldsymbol t)$, $g(\boldsymbol t)$ and $h(\boldsymbol t)$ are non-linear functions in $\boldsymbol t$. Note that $\boldsymbol{c}$ is a column vector independent of $\boldsymbol t$ and $I^{-1}(\boldsymbol t)$ is a pd matrix. Also observe that $\phi(\boldsymbol t)$ depends on $\boldsymbol t$ only through $I^{-1}(\boldsymbol t)$. I guess $\phi(\boldsymbol t)$ is convex w.r.t. to $I^{-1}(\boldsymbol t)$. Is it then convex w.r.t. to $\boldsymbol t$ as well?

Comment: Why should it be? Take e.g. $I^{-1}(t)=f(t)\cdot H$ where $H$ is a constant pd matrix and $f(t)>0$. Then $\phi(t)=C\cdot f(t)$ convex iff $f$ convex. Do you know anything about the nonlinear functions $f,g,h$?

Comment: What kind conditions that these functions need to satisfy? Those functions have extremely complicated form in my case. I of course want to minimise the quadratic form.